# PHP парсинг закомментированного кода с помощью preg_match_all()

Tags: preg_match, php, синтаксический-анализ

Есть код html странички:

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Главная</a></li>
<!--
        ...
        <li><a href="about.php">О компании</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.php">Новости</a></li>
        <li><a href="mail.php">Написать нам</a></li>
        ...
        еще что-нибудь
-->

        <!-- комментарий в одну строку -->

        <li><a href="cont.php">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Как в PHP с помощью функции "preg_match_all()" выдрать все незакомментированные ссылки?
Т.е. только вот эти:
index.php
cont.php

Comment: Добавьте модификатор s! И уберите i, он тут ни к чему.

Comment: Спасибо. С модификаторами разобрался.
Меняю вопрос :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName("a") as $link) {
    $url = $link->getAttribute("href");
    echo $url."\n";
}
```

И не париться по поводу регулярок.

Comment: > не париться по поводу регулярок

Золотые слова ))